# Phone ReGex to accept also letters after checking the first 3 or 4

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I have found this awesome regex here in stack overflow and added the additional formats i need for my phone validation. But now I am asked to allow the following:

```
(555)YOU-RULE
(555) MEI-YOUN
(555)YOURULE
555YOURULE
555 YOU RULE
555-YOU-RULE
```

And all the above with the 1 before them. I am not sure how to do that given the solution I have below for none aphanumeric numbers

Only numeric:

```
  var formats = "(999)999-9999|999-999-9999|(999) 999-9999|1(999) 999-9999|1(999)999-9999|999 999 9999|999.999.9999|1.999.999.9999|9999999999";
  var r = RegExp("^(" +
       formats
         .replace(/([\(\)])/g, "\\$1")
         .replace(/9/g,"\\d") +
       ")$");
    phoneOK = r.test(phone);
```

Comment: it's worth pointing out that your expression will only validate American format phone numbers. Most overseas countries use different formatting. This may or may not matter to you, depending on your target audience, but it's worth mentioning anyway for the benefit of others who may be reading this question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways of doing this however less legible for those not intimately familiar with regex. So if you want to keep using this method, you should first understand what's going on here.

You are converting a custom syntax to regex and what you need to focus on is the `9` that you are converting to be any digit, you'll need to allow this to be any digit or letter.

This conversion is happening in line 5:

```
.replace(/9/g,"\\d") +
```

`\d` is the term for any digit so we'll have to make it mean any digit or letter. The easiest way to do this would likely be to change it to `[\dA-Z]`. I'm making the assumption here that you only want uppercase, if you also want lowercase change it to: `[\dA-Za-z]`.

```
.replace(/9/g,"[\\dA-Z]") +
```

However, looking at your examples it looks like you also want only numbers in the first three digits. This will need a new rule. Let's call it `0` and update the formats accordingly:

```
var formats = "(000)999-9999|000-999-9999|(000) 999-9999|1(000) 999-9999|1(00)999-9999|000 999 9999|000.999.9999|1.000.999.9999|0009999999";
```

Now add the conversion after line 5:

```
.replace(/0/g,"\\d") +
```

You'll notice that it's the same as the old line 5.

So altogether we get:

```
var formats = "(000)999-9999|000-999-9999|(000) 999-9999|1(000) 999-9999|1(00)999-9999|000 999 9999|000.999.9999|1.000.999.9999|0009999999";
var r = RegExp("^(" +
   formats
     .replace(/([\(\)])/g, "\\$1")
     .replace(/9/g,"[\\dA-Z]")
     .replace(/0/g,"\\d") +
   ")$");
phoneOK = r.test(phone);
```

Comment: You are awesome man, thanks for the explanation. It is very clear now. The reason why I chose this one is because eventually we will build out something to allow users to pick their validations.

Comment: @ergwin, FWI: I just tested it and made a small amendment to line 5.